# Making API call from a Pipeline job in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, jobs

Would it be possible to make an API call from a Gitlab Pipeline job? I am investigating to see if we can replace the clicking of a button on our Swagger Ui and instead add the API call to a gitlab pipeline job to automate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can make api calls from a Gitlab job using `curl` very easily. Here is the simplest example of a Gitlab job with a `curl` command to your Swagger endpoint:

```
stages:
  - api_call

call_swagger_api:
  stage: api_call
  script:
    - curl -X POST https://your-swagger-url.com/api/endpoint
```

Other methods like `wget` will also work if you install them in your pipeline.